# Enable Robocopy logs

Tags: windows, robocopy

I have a `robocopy` job that is controlled by Windows Task Scheduler to run every 15 minutes to move files from one server to another.  According to Windows Task Scheduler, the job is running fine.  However - none of the files are being moved.

Here is the full script:

```
net use v: \\serverone /user:UserName PassWord
robocopy v:\ "\\servertwo\folder" /MOV
net use v: /d /yes
exit
```

Is there a way to add logging to the robocopy job that would capture an error so I can find why the files are no being moved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From robocopy /?

```
::
:: Logging Options :
::
                 /L :: List only - don't copy, timestamp or delete any files.
                 /X :: report all eXtra files, not just those selected.
                 /V :: produce Verbose output, showing skipped files.
                /TS :: include source file Time Stamps in the output.
                /FP :: include Full Pathname of files in the output.
             /BYTES :: Print sizes as bytes.

                /NS :: No Size - don't log file sizes.
                /NC :: No Class - don't log file classes.
               /NFL :: No File List - don't log file names.
               /NDL :: No Directory List - don't log directory names.

                /NP :: No Progress - don't display percentage copied.
               /ETA :: show Estimated Time of Arrival of copied files.

          /LOG:file :: output status to LOG file (overwrite existing log).
         /LOG+:file :: output status to LOG file (append to existing log).

       /UNILOG:file :: output status to LOG file as UNICODE (overwrite existing log).
      /UNILOG+:file :: output status to LOG file as UNICODE (append to existing log).

               /TEE :: output to console window, as well as the log file.

               /NJH :: No Job Header.
               /NJS :: No Job Summary.

           /UNICODE :: output status as UNICODE.
```

So I would try something like:

```
robocopy v:\ "\\servertwo\folder" /MOV /V /LOG:file.log
```

Comment: Note as pointed out that will overwrite the logs.

Comment: robocopy v:\ "\\servertwo\folder" /MOV /V /LOG+:file.log

Answer (score 3):

From [Robocopy: Command-line Usage Examples and Switches](https://sumtips.com/how-to/robocopy-command-line-usage-examples-and-switches/)

Example 13: Log only errors into a text file:

```
robocopy C:\Folder1 C:\Backup /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /NC /NP >> log.txt
```

Instead of `>> log.txt`, you can use `/LOG+:log.txt`.  LOG+ does an append