# How to determine which file failed to copy?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, copy

I am copying a directory with hundreds of nested subdirectories using Windows Explorer (Windows 10).  This takes a long time.

I received an error dialog stating that a file cannot be copied.  `Try again` repeatedly fails.

I repeated the copy operation, which failed again with the same error.

It is extremely important that every single file gets copied, so I need to be able to manually troubleshoot and fix this issue.

Unfortunately, the error dialog only contains the filename, no filepath.  "More details" does not reveal a filepath.  I can't see or find any way of determining what the filepath of this file is.  There are hundreds of copies with this filename.

How can I determine which file failed?

Comment: Take exlusive ownership of every file, you are attempting to copy, by taking control over the root folder.  When prompted to apply the permissions to all files, you should select that option, otherwise you won't be solving anything.

Comment: I cannot take ownership because there is no security tab in the file properties.

Comment: The files are on a flash drive.

Comment: NTFS or FAT32.  The Security tab being absent makes it sound like it’s FAT32.

Comment: Have you tried using the robocopy command line command to copy instead?
With robocopy you can generate a log of the copying process, as explored in the post [Enable Robocopy Logs](https://superuser.com/questions/437401/enable-robocopy-logs), and use it to more easily locate the specific files giving you issues.